# Comparing the results of two scalar functions

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I'm new to scalar functions and the like, so please explain if I'm doing something hideously wrong (there's a good chance). I'm trying to compare the results from two different scalar functions that both return an `INT` but no matter the syntax, I get errors about it.

`SELECT dbo.function1(@param1) = SELECT dbo.function2(@param2, @param3, @param4)`

Ideally, this would be run as part of the `WHERE` clause in a larger query if at all possible, since `@param1` is taken from an earlier part of the larger query.

Comment: It's just all depend on your function logic. I think there's no need to compare.

Comment: Function depends on your code construction. Not depends from anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the second 'select'. If you are looking to compare the numbers/integers within the query you can always use a case statement.

Comment: Can you explain why the select isn't needed? I just tried that and it fails still. Also, not entirely sure how I would compare them using a case statement?

Comment: Because there is a 'select' already. There is only need for one 'Select' per query.

Comment: Regarding the case statement; **Case when dbo.function1(@param1) = dbo.function2(@param2, @param3, @param4) then ... else ... end**.    see more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql

Comment: OK, but `SELECT dbo.function1(@param1) = dbo.function2(@param2, @param3, @param4)` still causes syntax errors at the '='. A case statement seems excessive. This is basically the same as `WHERE 1=1`.

Comment: Correct, because you cannot select two things equaling each other. That is why you would need to place it in a 'case statement'. Once you compare it you can output a desired result.

Comment: I believe my problem was using the `SELECT` within the `WHERE` clause. Calling the function directly seems to have done the job. Thanks.